# Using textalk/websocket on codeigniter to connect to websocket server doesn't work

Tags: php, nginx, websocket, plesk, codeigniter-4

I am getting
`Connection to 'wss://sub.example.com' failed: Server sent invalid upgrade response: HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway`

I can connect to the server using socket.io from another page in the app using JS no problem, this is the code for that:

```
        const socket = io('wss://sub.example.com');
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('connected to server');
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('disconnected from server');
    });
```

But when I try to connect to it using PHP from the same application it doesn't work. I am trying to send a message and see it on the other page while it's connected.

I had a hard time setting it up, I am using plesk so had to make a subdomain, turn off proxy and add nginx directives, this is the code for that:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
}
```

Here is a more detailed view of the error

```
Connection to 'wss://sub.example.com' failed: Server sent invalid upgrade response: HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 11:11:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=alGVrw0IPgYtL0TnWm%2FItR0tfiENHO1A5fD4aPgK8g5eLKkbZkDvHc3qeJ%2FKgMkr8%2BWJrCgb1INp%2FKc%2FfVwlSLTDGAMYAxOS1%2BGFNvzlXDVZv%2BEjJ04WkhSEqSymz9lfVxIiNNtqjVuDAFP3eqICb4U%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 79e7c25f79bd4185-LHR
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
```

What is wrong?

EDIT*****

This is my model incase anyone want to see it

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use WebSocket\Client as WebSocketClient;

class WebsocketModel extends \CodeIgniter\Model {

protected $websocket;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function connect($url) {
    $this->websocket = new WebSocketClient($url);
}

public function send($data) {
    // Construct the Socket.IO message format
    $message = "42[\"my-event\"," . json_encode($data) . "]";
    
    // Send the message to the server
    $this->websocket->send($message);
}

}
```